# Can't add reference to HttpBaseProtocolFilter

Tags: c#

I am coding a tool in C# with Visual Studio 2015 that queries a webserver and need authentification against a IBM webseal. Therefor I read in the internet it is possible to do the authentification with a HttpBaseProtocolFilter. But I cannot use it in my program as there is an error. "The Type- or namespacename 'HttpBaseProtocolFilter' was not found (missing using or assembly directive?)"

The documentation under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter says

Namespace:    Windows.Web.Http.Filters

Assemblies:   Windows.Web.Http.Filters.dll, Windows.dll

But I cannot find it in the IDE under  -  (hope I translated it correctly).
Hope you got a hint where to look for it.

Comment: That's a UWP class. Are you building a UWP application? The HttpClient class used in any other application (desktop, ASP.NET, Core or otherwise) is completely different and doesn't use HttpBaseProtocolFilter

Comment: BTW don't `read in the internet`. Understand what you are doing, read the documentation, tutorials and courses. It's faster than trying random things that may not be related to what you are doing after all

Comment: I am building a VSTO-application. So maybe there is a different approach in that case.

Comment: That's a *huge* difference. UWP are the App store classes that run on a restricted runtime. In the Full Framework and .NET Core HttpClient lives in the System.Net.HttpClient namespace. You can add the latest version throug the [System.Net.HttpClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/) Nuget package